# What is the difference between さしあげる and あげる?

Tags: meaning, words

I realize that both words mean to give. What is the difference between さしあげる and あげる? The word was used in a chat with an elderly person.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/6461/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12584/9831

Answer (score 3, accepted):

差{さ}し上{あ}げる is the honorific version of あげる: it os used to show respect to the person you're talking to.

It is used the same way as あげる in combination with the て form of a verb to express that the speaker offers an action to the interlocutor.

> 手伝って差し上げましょうか。
>
> Shall I help you?

On the other hand, 与{あた}える can be used to express the action of giving, but to a person of lower status.

I have never seen 与える used with the て form of a verb though, but ~てやる can be used to express the same meaning as ~てあげる but toward a person of lower status.